# Transmission Dip stick reading at Hot level

Tags: brakes, transmission, gmc, abs, jimmy

I just bought a 2000 GMC Jimmy with 170,012 miles on it. Is it normal that it is reading hot on the dip stick of the tranny fluid? yes this is after its been running for awhile.Also the previous owner replaced breaks both pads and calipers and the ABS light is on,however she says she doesn't recall if it was on prior to changing them (it was her sons car) could the change have triggered the light to come on due to the sensors? or is this evidence of further problems.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm puzzled - what is it you are asking? Can you delete the stuff about the ABS light - it's a separate question, and with the info you have here it's too broad - to focus on the transmission question. If it's just, "Should this read hot after running for a while?" then the answer is yes :-)

Comment: You should be able to check the function of your ABS sensors with a multi-meter, and as Rory said, yes, the tranny fluid should read hot after it's been running for a while.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the reading on the stick.  The Hot mark doesn't mean the fluid is overly hot...  That is the *full* mark when the fluid is hot (which is normal).  Transmissions are supposed to be checked after the engine is up to temperature and has been driving a while.

Answer (score 1):

Reading hot on the transmission dipstick after driving is normal.

As to the ABS light they could of damaged wiring while doing the brakes but it's unlikely. Reading ABS codes requires a scantool capable of talking to the ABS computer.

Comment: Not just a scan tool, but one capable of reading ABS codes. Most auto stores which read codes don't have the right scan tool. I know you know that, I just thought I'd spell it out for our audience.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 right on I was thinking it but it never made it into the post.